# rails aborted! Don't know how to build task 'task_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I was creating a quick one-off task:

```
require 'yaml'

task generate_permissions_yaml: :environment do
  permissions = []

  Permission.order(:title).each do |permission|
    permissions << {
      title: permission.title,
      code: permission.code,
      description: permission.description
    }
  end

  puts permissions.to_yaml
end
```

When I ran it with `rails generate_permissions_yaml`, I got this error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate_permissions_yaml' (see --tasks)
/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it was due to the way that I named the file. It should have a `.rake` extension, not `.rb`.

I renamed this:

```
lib/tasks/generate_permissions_yaml.rb
```

To this:

```
lib/tasks/generate_permissions_yaml.rake
```

I uncovered this after trying to run `rails g task generate_permissions_yaml` and seeing that it generated a file with a `.rake` extension.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was beating my head against a wall for the better part of an hour trying to figure out why my task wasn't running.

Answer (score -1):

For newbies - this is a common error if you use a space instead of a colon in a rake command. For example if you enter:

```
rake db migrate
```

instead of:

```
rake db:migrate
```

The correct format has a colon, not a space

Comment: While what you posted is true, it does not really address this particular question.  It is a well written answer for the wrong question.